# Using connect() with React/Redux/TypeScript cannot find property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I want to access the properties and methods on distinct components using the `connect()` functionality, but I'm having trouble defining this the right way. What I currently have in my `redux`-folder:

**/redux/app/hooks.ts**

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store';

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

**/redux/app/store.ts**

```
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import rootReducer from "..";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType, RootState, unknown, Action<string>>;
```

**/redux/index.ts**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import userReducer from "./modules/user";

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**/redux/modules/user.ts**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/createAction";
import { User } from "../../models/user";

interface UserState {
  user: User | null;
}

const initUserState = { user: null } as UserState;

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: initUserState,
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<User>) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setUser } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

This looks pretty okay to me.

So I have the following `Wrapper` component which acts as the layout in which the child components reside.

**Wrapper.ts**

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { User } from "../models/user";
import Menu from "./Menu";
import Nav from "./Nav";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { setUser } from "../redux/modules/user";
import { RootState } from "../redux/app/store";

export interface WrapperProps {}

const Wrapper: React.FC<WrapperProps> = (props) => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("user");

        if (res.status === 200) {
          props.setUser(res.data as User);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        setRedirect(true);
      }
    })();
  }, [props]);

  if (redirect) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Nav />

      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <Menu />

          <main className="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
            {props.children}
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const mapState = (state: RootState) => ({ user: state.user });
const mapDispatch = { setUser };
const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch);

export default connector(Wrapper);
```

In the `Wrapper`, I'm getting an error when I try to set the user in `useEffect` with `props.setUser`, stating: `Property 'setUser' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<WrapperProps>'`.

I also want to access this user in the Nav-component which is a child of `Wrapper`. This looks like the following:

**Nav.ts**

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "../redux/app/store";

export interface NavProps {}

const Nav: React.FC<NavProps> = (props) => {
  const logoutHandler = async () => await axios.post("logout", {});

  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
      <span className="company">Company Name</span>
      <ul className="my02 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
        <Link to="/profile" className="p-2 text-white text-decoration-none">
          {props.user.name}
        </Link>
        <Link to="/login" onClick={logoutHandler}
          className="p-2 text-white text-decoration-none">
          Sign out
        </Link>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({ user: state.user });
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Nav);
```

In `Nav` I get an error when I try to access `props.user.name`, stating: `Property 'user' does not exist on type 'PropsWithChildren<NavProps>'`.

Any ideas on how to do this with Redux Toolkit and TypeScript? If you have suggestions on refactoring/optimizing the code above, let me know as well. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using the old way with the connect HOC instead of using the useSelector hook?

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, you're using an empty interface, which isn't sufficient. Try the following, straight from https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript

```
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux'

const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>

// Use this type for the props of your component!!
type Props = PropsFromRedux & {
   // ... non-redux-related props here
}
```

The second problem is probably solved with the same pattern. TS support is much better if you're using the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks. The RTK docs explain how to set these up in a way you never have to type them again, anywhere in your app. You would simply use an `useAppDispatch` that knows which actions exist in your app, and a version of `useSelector` that knows the exact shape of your store.